# Public dumps for mathoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

As far as I remember, there was supposed to be a public dump of the MO database just before the migration: http://dumps.mathoverflow.net/ . Not an urgency by any measure, but something that would be quite helpful.

**EDIT:** Much of the info in the answers is now obsolete. The current go-to place for the public dumps of both mathoverflow and math.stackexchange is https://archive.org/details/stackexchange .

Comment: I posted a recent dump at [dumps.mathoverflow.net](http://dumps.mathoverflow.net). I did grab another full database dump a few hours before migration, but it hasn't been cleaned up yet.

Comment: Very nice; thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The September 2013 dump (the first since we've moved to 2.0) has just become available.

It's in the form of a 14GB torrent for all the Stack Exchange sites, but you can ask your torrent client to only download the MathOverflow specific files (~130mb).

Comment: As indicated in Anna Lear's answer, the torrent can be accessed [here](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump).

Answer (score 16):

MathOverflow will be added to our public [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) in a couple of weeks and it will also be included in our [network-wide data dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump).

All of the data (minus deleted stuff) should also be accessible via our [API](http://api.stackexchange.com).

I'm not sure off the top of my head what the options are (if any) for setting up a site-specific data dump. Please let me know if the data explorer is not sufficient for your needs once MathOverflow can be queried there.

Comment: +1 and ✓ for the network-wide dump which answers my question from the theoretical perspective. I have to admit I'd value site-specific dumps more, though.

Comment: Could you give an updated estimate of how long it will be until MO is added to the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I'm sorry, I don't have a better estimate at the moment. I'm following up with the devs to see what's what.

Comment: OK. When you have some idea, it would be great if you could post an answer to [this question](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/634/21564).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Will do.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese there was a glitch with the new site imports (which is supposed to be automated, once a site graduates) after the move to NY while we rebuild Oregon.  I have just fixed the glitch and the first import of MO has completed.  It will update once a week every Sunday now.

Comment: What happened to clearbits.net? The site doesn't seem to load.

Comment: @darijgrinberg No idea, unfortunately. We don't run it. We'll try to reach them and see what's up.

Comment: By now it seems that clearbits is dead. Care to look for a replacement? By now I suspect that even piratebay is less likely to go down...

Comment: @darijgrinberg We had no warning whatsoever and Clearbits shutting down took us entirely by surprise. We are actively looking for a replacement and are in talks to move our data dumps elsewhere, but it's probably gonna take some time still to sort this out.

Comment: @Adam since you're still on staff, I guess I should ping you to ask if we are going to get a data dump now, regardless of the rest of the network. People are unhappy particularly because MO is slightly special in this regard.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I don't know but let me see if I can find out.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Please reach out to [Philippe](https://mathoverflow.net/users/176540/philippe). His email is in his profile bio.

Answer (score 14):

Just to bump this question: [StackExchange Inc. turned off the periodic network-wide data dump earlier this year, and it can apparently only be resumed with permission from very high in the company](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390023/226541). I guess this includes MO. I haven't heard otherwise.

So we are probably missing some of our more recent data.

---

Edit: now reinstated https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390200/226541 after a lot of push-back.

Answer (score 6):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) is an alternative.

Answer (score 6):

The data dumps happen quarterly, so I think we can expect the next one to appear in September. For anyone who needs to know asap, here's the RSS feed that reports the availability of new dumps:

> http://www.clearbits.net/feeds/creator/146-stack-exchange-data-dump.rss

Note that these dumps are a torrent for the entire stack exchange network; there's a separate file inside for each site. Most bittorrent clients can be told to only download specific files, and this should let you just pull out the MathOverflow specific parts.