# The data explorer on MO

Tags: support, status-completed

I don't seem to be able to use http://data.stackexchange.com/ on MathOverflow.

> Will this change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Public dumps for mathoverflow?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/129/public-dumps-for-mathoverflow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data explorer now supports MathOverflow. See, for example,

> [Most prolific editors on MathOverflow](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/6627/top-50-most-prolific-editors)

(For those not sure what this means: essentially you can write SQL queries against the (public parts of) the MathOverflow database, and run and save them through a nice web interface.)

Answer (score 9):

It's not there yet, but will be within a few weeks. There's additional work for the SE folks to hook this up, and it's lower priority than the main migration (and probably many other things). See [Public dumps for mathoverflow?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/129/public-dumps-for-mathoverflow) for details.