# How long until MathOverflow will be part of the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

According to [this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/133/21564) and [this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/407/21564), MathOverflow will eventually appear on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/). A couple of weeks have passed since these answers were given and MO is still missing from the Data Explorer. Which leads me to the question:

> How long until MathOverflow will be part of the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

I just want an updated estimate from someone who has some idea about this issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[According to Nick Craver](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/129/public-dumps-for-mathoverflow/133?noredirect=1#comment2851_133),

> there was a glitch with the new site imports (which is supposed to be automated, once a site graduates) after the move to NY while we rebuild Oregon. I have just fixed the glitch and the first import of MO has completed. It will update once a week every Sunday now.

Please let us know if there are any problems with this in the future.

Comment: Anna (and Nick!): Thank you very much for your work!