# Studying the MathOverflow data dump with Mathematica

Tags: discussion, data-dump

This is just a mention of some work Wolfram has done recently, allowing you to import a database dump of MathOverflow and analyse it within Mathematica.

[The Data Science of MathOverflow](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/02/01/the-data-science-of-mathoverflow/)

Their example analyses are maybe not the most exciting, but it does seem a quite powerful tool for anyone with Mathematica experience, if there's something you'd like to learn from the database dumps.

Comment: Some of the data shown there can be obtained already by [Data Explorer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info), which was available [for some time](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/634/how-long-until-mathoverflow-will-be-part-of-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer). But using Mathematica clearly adds new possibilities.

Comment: I see that both “gerhard ask me about system design” and “ask me about system design paseman” make it, albeit in small font, into the word cloud of 6-grams. The word cloud of 7-grams is not shown ...

Comment: Just goes to show, if you want to make it big in this word (cloud), you have to keep at it.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2019.02.10.

Comment: The equations analysis is good, eg: What is the most common equation on MathOverflow? (If the post had a table of contents I would link there.) Apparently the answer is $n=2$.

Comment: Possibly looking at some older questions tagged ([meta-tag:statistics]) might give some indication what MO users were interested in the past. (And somebody familiar with Mathematica might be able to check whether this software is suitable for some of them.)